# Spring boot - How to specify different location for rotated tomcat log file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, log4j, tomcat8

I have a spring boot application. The access log of embedded tomcat is configured to rotate daily with time stamp suffix in application.properties. My requirement is to generate the rotated log file into an archive folder. but I could not find any configuration to specify the location for rotated file in application.properties. Does anyone know how achieve this?

all the latest log will be in /logs folder and 
all the rotated log file should be in /logs/archive folder. - How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, finally i figured out a way to do this using logback access.

Include the following dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.rakugakibox.spring.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>logback-access-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Also create a logback-access.xml in resources folder with following configuration.

```
<configuration>
    <property resource="application.properties" />
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>logs/dev_access.log</file>
        <rollingPolicy
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>logs/Archive/dev_access_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%h %l %u %t "%r" %s %b  %D</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a DailySchedular class to do that job . Use `@EnableScheduling` and a `@Scheduled` method that will wake up once a day, scan the wanted directory according to the date, and remove the wanted files to the archive directory.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What I am looking for is something similar to what logback offers. In log back we can specify the rolling policy where we can mention the file like <fileNamePattern>Archive/app.log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}</fileNamePattern>